# Unable to use tools from the dotnet CLI on Linux Manjaro

Tags: c#, .net, neovim, dotnet-cli, nvim-lspconfig

I am currently trying to setup a lsp server for c# in my nvim configuration.
I want to use csharp-ls as my lsp server. But it seems like I'm not able to use the tool with the .Net CLI.

I am using Mason as lsp manager and upon editing a .cs file here is what I have:
[image: LspInfo command]

So here it seems that csharp-ls is correctly setup and defined in my configuration but the client can't be attached to my session.

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-use) from Microsoft.

I tried to use the tool from my terminal, the tool is correctly installed:
[Csharp-ls install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfvAX.png)

But it seems like its unable to use it:
[error on csharp-ls usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q45s.png)

Maybe this bug with the .Net CLI isn4t related to why my Nvim can't find the lsp client but it might be related.
If someone has any clue I would really appreciate !

Comment: its not related to your neovim config, how did you install _dotnet_?

Comment: @MonsieurMerso thanks for the answer ! To install dotnet, i have follow [this microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) but I needed to install the version 7.0 to use csharp_ls correctly. So i used the script as they say in their example `./dotnet-install.sh --channel 7.0`, i have the correct sdks and runtime installed too,

Comment: I'm not a _dotnet tool_ expert, may be it was installed for a wrong framework, try removing _csharp-ls_ and reinstalling it with _--framework_ flag. Some [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @MonsieurMerso but unfortunately it didn't worked for me